# Rails jsonb search in all attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb field in my postgres database that contains some user info, and I have a search box in my app which query the jsonb field, if for example I want to search for a user name I do

```
where('user_details ->> :key LIKE :value', key: "name", value: "%#{term}%")
```

What I would like to do instead is to search in all the keys of the jsonb field, something that will be translated like this :

```
where('user_details ->> :all_keys LIKE :value', value: "%#{term}%")
```

Comment: Have you found a solution :) ?

Comment: @gal I really don't remember what I was doing back then, maybe I changed the way I structured the json and built my own search function (you can always change how to think about things) or possible that I found some other kind of solution, I'm currently working on an old project and I found that I'm using a gem https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search I don't remember what it does neither but you can check it maybe you can find on it something useful or an idea, who knows! in case I find an answer by luck to this I will make sure to post it ;)